# How can I get that extra Praxis case?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution, the-missing-link

Early on in the game I spotted a Praxis case in the cargo area of the ship. See this image link:

[image]

[image]

The best I've done is what's in pic 2. Any ideas if this is possible to get?

Comment: Embedded the image for ya.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that. :)  both pics are here: http://imgur.com/a/sjdtc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get two praxis cases in this area

1. If you have upgraded jump, go to Floor #1 and jump up the containers. You should also be able to juggle around the crates to stack them up to a jumpable height.
2. If you have the strength upgrade, break through the wall after getting #1.

Comment: See my comment to CyberSkull. There are 2 separate praxis locations involved here.

Answer (score 1):

The [*Deus Ex* Wikia](http://deusex.wikia.com/) has a very complete list of where to find all the [Praxis Kits](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Praxis_Kit). You can find the ones for "The Missing Link" [here](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Praxis_Kit#Locations_.28The_Missing_Link.29).

Comment: Actually the Wikia is wrong. There are 2 separate praxis kits available so the 2 ways give you 2 praxis points. I did it with extra jump and 2 boxes then I used that praxis to get punch through walls to get the other one.

Comment: @DanHoward Then correct it!

Comment: If I do that then the CIA will know where I am. ;) OK I'll correct it at some point.

Comment: @DanHoward where is the second kit?  I got the first one (pictured in the question), then I broke the wall and killed the soldier, but I can't find the kit.